# Is $0 \le p_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}p_{n-k} \le 2^{-n}$ where $p_0= 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $(p_n)_n$ be the sequence defined by $p_0 = 1$ and
$$p_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}p_{n-k}.$$
Using Python, I notice that $0 \le p_n \le \frac{1}{2^n}$.
I was unable to prove it by induction.
Is is true? In this case, how to prove it?

Comment: Try proving the stronger claim $1/3 * p_{n - 1} \leq p_n \leq 1/2 * p_{n - 1}$ by induction.

Comment: Just a note: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n z^{2n}=\sec z$ met [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't explain where that comes from, and why your specific $p_n\le2^{-n}$ would matter. I guess that could be proved, as the real asymptotics is $p_n\sim(4/\pi^2)^n$ (yes, that follows easily from what @metamorphy said in a comment), and $4/\pi^2<1/2$.
And yes, I'm aware this is no answer, it should be a comment, but I don't have the "reputation" for that. So you'd better hurry reading this, before the Taliban get it deleted. ;)